# Find out why SSH connection crashed under Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, pipe, logfiles

My SSH connection broke with "Error: Broken Pipe". After this the server I was connected to was down. The logfiles on the server were checked and nothing could be found.

I now have to scan the logfiles on my machine to find traces why the connection broke.

- Which logfiles do I have to scan?
- What patterns do I have to look for?
- How long does Ubuntu store these files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your connection drops for any reasons or if your connection was idle for too long. It is more likely to do with idle connection settings, you can change the keepalive settings on your client or server, see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/what-does-the-broken-pipe-message-mean-in-an-ssh-session) for how you can change that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However the fact that the server crashed after the connection broke suggests that something else could be the problem...